Why is sound studied in superconductors and superfluids
Why do people studying superconductivity, superfluidity, Bose Einstein condensates study the properties of sound like speed and dispersion relation? what is the importance of studying these things?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_sound for one.

Curiosity. What if... oh, that's unexpected...

Superconductivity comes from electrons forming a superfluid due to their interactions with sound. You could have just read up on the Nobel prize for it.
